# Embeddable web server for a WinForms app that can serve ASP.NET Web API

Tags: windows, web-server, web-apis, asp.net

Somewhat related to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17601/simple-deployable-web-server), I'm looking for a web server for Windows that I can include/embed into my WinForms application:

- Must be able to host, run and serve ASP.NET Web API.
- Must be able to serve static files (like e.g. images).
- Must be shippable with my application's setup.
- Must be installable/deployable without administrative privileges.
- Must be usable without having the user to run my application (or the setup of the application) with administrative privileges).

Maybe I can go with [Cassini web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412190/how-to-download-cassini-webserver-source-code) but I'm looking for more professional/up-to-date alternatives, including commercial ones.

The web server itself can be pretty limited:

- Only need to be used from within the application itself.
- Only need to work locally.
- Needs no authentication.

**My question:**

Can someone recommend me solutions that meet the above criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some weeks of searching and trying (and discarding) various solutions, I found the [Kestrel web server](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#kestrel) integrated into .NET Core the most suitable thing (see also [my similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38906739/107625)).

There is [a fantastic example over at Rick Strahl's weblog](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/29/First-Steps-Exploring-NET-Core-and-ASPNET-Core) ([GitHub repository with the whole example](https://github.com/RickStrahl/AspNetCoreFromScratchSample)) on how to use Kestrel together with ASP.NET Core Web API and even MVC.

Since .NET Core can ship completely without dependencies (see below), I could go with a scenario similar to something like this:

1. Include a complete Kestrel project into my setup executable.
2. Include my "normal" WinForms application into my setup executable.

Then, I have something completely stand-alone with no external web server dependencies.

You can also use the [Kestrel web server](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#kestrel) in a "normal" .NET Framework project, e.g. .NET 4.6.1. Simply add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel`NuGet package as a reference.

---

**Ship .NET Core Framework**

Just as a reference for others and my future self, here is how to ship the whole .NET Core Framework binaries with your application:

1. Edit "project.json".
2. Remove the `"type": "platform"` from the `"Microsoft.NETCore.App"` dependencies.
3. Add `"runtimes": { "win10-x64": {} }` (or others if required).
4. Publish.

See the bottom section "*All right, but they told that this is similar to java! Can I publish a really self-contained asp.net application, which also ships the framework?*" on the ["project.json settings in asp.net core" blog article](http://kalapos.azurewebsites.net/project-json-settings-in-asp-net-core) for more details.